# How can I add 'foxy' as an acceptable version-tag on awswers.ros.org

Tags: ros, ros2, meta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Instruction for tags is:

> "You must at least tag the rosdistro you are using, such as indigo, kinetic, lunar, melodic, or ardent."

The error text if you fail to comply is:

> "At least one of the following tags is required : boxturtle, cturtle, diamondback, electric, fuerte, groovy, hydro, indigo, jade, kinetic, lunar, melodic, noetic, r2b3, ardent, bouncy, crystal, dashing, eloquent, ros1 or ros2"

shouldn't theses match? and why no love for Foxy? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358952/how-can-i-add-%27foxy%27-as-an-acceptable-version-tag-on-awswers.ros.org/) by [dawonn_haval](https://answers.ros.org/users/52574/dawonn_haval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2020-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is something that only the ROS Answers admins can do.

This may change with the Askbot version, but there should be an list of "Mandatory tags" on this page:

https://answers.ros.org/settings/FORUM_DATA_RULES/

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2020-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dawonn_haval](https://answers.ros.org/users/52574/dawonn_haval/) on 2020-08-07**:
How does one go about notifying an admin about such a thing? Is there an issue tracker somewhere?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) on 2020-08-07**:
Here it is: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org